# Поиск файлов по расширению c#

Tags: c#, windows, файлы

такая проблема: Есть код, который получает все файлы с данным расширением.

```cs
string[] mainfile = Directory.GetFiles(mySettings.LocaleSettingsModel.PathToMainFile, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Собственно, имеются и файлы с расширением .text_res, и при использовании кода выше, считываются и они.

```cs
string[] mainfile = Directory.GetFiles(mySettings.LocaleSettingsModel.PathToMainFile, "~>.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Использовав данный код, вообще ничего не возвращает, хотя шаблон в винде работает.

Собственно вопрос, как взять только файлы с расширением .txt, не перебирая файлы в foreach и писать так file.endwith(".txt"); ?

Comment: Сразу вопрос: у вас включено отображение расширений **зарегистрированных** типов файлов? Просто под маску `*.txt` никак не может попасть `.text_res`, кроме случая, когда реальное расширение зарегистрировано, скрыто и, на самом деле именно `*.txt`. Ну и полагаю вы в курсе, что Windows считает расширением символы с конца имени до первой с конца точки, т.е. какой-нибудь `*.tar.gz` для системы имеет расширение `.gz`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня в моем тестовом примере все нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть у вас файлы имеют такие именования:

blablabla.text_res.txt, но в винде у вас отключено показывание расширения файлов и вы видите blablabla.text_res и ошибочно полагаете, что они не должны попадать в выборку

Comment: о, ещё один linqpad юзер детектед. Теперь нас как минимум трое таких тут :)

Comment: @tym32167 а кто третий? я четвертым буду =) Злая и очень правильная штука для отработки прототипов алгоритмов и LiNQ-запросов

Comment: вы, я и @AK - юзеры - пропогандисты LinqPad :)